# How to process each word in a python program

Tags: python-3.x, loops, data-structures

I want to write a program that reads every word from every line of a text file.
I tried using nested loop but the second loop starts reading each word. Can someone explain this? Accodrding to me it should read the individual words instead of letters.

```
fh=open("romeo.txt")
d=dict()
c=0
for i in fh:
    for j in i:
        d[c]=j
        c+=1
print(d)
for i in d:
    print(d.get('moon',None))
```

the output is shown in [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz2W2.png)

I made a code which does the thing I want but is there any short way to do it?

```
fh=open("romeo.txt")
d=dict()
c=0
for i in fh:
    i=i.rstrip()
    print("by the first loop ######################", i)
    k=i.split()
    for j in k:
        print("by the second loop @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@", j)
        d[c]=j
        c+=1
print(d)
```

the output which I want is given in [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYA9t.png)

Also, can I use split() function here to do it?
How can I use it because it seems to get only the last line of the file as a list and I want all the words in list or dictionary.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in fh:
```

This line iterates through each line of text in the file

```
for j in i:
```

Since i is a string, this line iterates through each letter in each line. Instead of doing it this way, `split()` the line over whitespace and then iterate through the resulting list:

```
for line in fh:
    for word in line.split():
        #do stuff
```

Anyway since you wanted a short way to do it here's a neat one liner:

To make a list of each word in the file:

```
[word for line in open("romeo.txt") for word in line.split()]
```

To make a dict (list is better since your keys are integer indices anyway):

```
{c: i for c, i in enumerate([word for line in open("romeo.txt") for word in line.split()])}
```